# Trying to make this switch change the background color of the page

Tags: css, html, switch-statement

I am trying to make it so when you click it to pm mode the page background switches to black.

```
<div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn"/>
  <label for="dn" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler">
      <span class="crater crater--1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--3"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star star--1"></span>
    <span class="star star--2"></span>
    <span class="star star--3"></span>
    <span class="star star--4"></span>
    <span class="star star--5"></span>
    <span class="star star--6"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<style>

body {
  background-color: #ffffff00;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Rounded', 'Arial Rounded MT Bold','Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: ffffff;
}
```

Switch Style. I am trying to make it so when you click it to pm mode the page background switches to black.

```
.toggleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 200px;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.toggleWrapper input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99em;
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #83D8FF;
  border-radius: 84px;
  transition: background-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
.toggle:before {
  content: 'AM';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;

}
.toggle:after {
  content: 'PM';
  position: absolute;
  right: -48px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #749ED7;
.bgcolor;

}

.toggle__handler {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #FFCF96;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.toggle__handler .crater {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #E8CDA5;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.toggle__handler .crater--1 {
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
.toggle__handler .crater--2 {
  top: 28px;
  left: 22px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}
.toggle__handler .crater--3 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.star--1 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 35px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--2 {
  top: 18px;
  left: 28px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--3 {
  top: 27px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--4,
.star--5,
.star--6 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

.star--4 {
  top: 16px;
  left: 11px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}

.star--5 {
  top: 32px;
  left: 17px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}

.star--6 {
  top: 36px;
  left: 28px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
```

I am trying to make it so when you click it to pm mode the page background switches to black.

```
input:checked + .toggle {
  background-color: #749DD6;
}
input:checked + .toggle:before {
  color: #749ED7;
}
input:checked + .toggle:after {
  color: #ffffff;
}
input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler {
  background-color: #FFE5B5;
  transform: translate3d(40px, 0, 0) rotate(0);
}
input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler .crater { 
  opacity: 1;
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--1 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--2 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
} 
input:checked + .toggle .star--3 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(-7px, 0, 0);
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--4,
input:checked + .toggle .star--5,
input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--4 {
  transition: all 300ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--5 {
   transition: all 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
  transition: all 300ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

}
```

VIEW SCSS CODE VIEW RESOURCES 1×
0.5×
0.25×

```
</style>
```

I am trying to make it so when you click it to pm mode the page background switches to black.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you will need javascript, it's the easier way,

Using native javascript :

```
var toggle = true; //mean that is the background is white
function test(){
    toggle ? document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black' : 
             document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    toggle = !toggle; //change the color background
}
```

And you just have to change that line in your html

`<label for="dn" class="toggle" onclick="test()">`

You can also use jquery :

```
var toggle = true
function test(){
     toggle ? $('body').css('background-color', 'black')
             :$('body').css('background-color', 'white');
     toggle = !toggle;
}
```